# How to use global userdefined class object

Tags: c++

In Friend.h

```
#ifndef FRIEND
#define FRIEND 
class Friend
{

public:
    static int i ;
    int j;
    Friend(void);
    ~Friend(void);
}frnd1;
#endif
```

In Friend.cpp

```
#include "Friend.h"
int Friend::i = 9;
extern Friend frnd1;
Friend::Friend(void)
{
}

Friend::~Friend(void)
{
}
```

In main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"Friend.h"

int main()
{
frnd1.j = 9;
cout<<"hello";
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, its gives the following linker error:

```
error LNK2005: "class Friend frnd1" (?frnd1@@3VFriend@@A) already defined in main.obj
```

I am unable to understand how to use the global object in main function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `frnd1` is *defined* in a header file, and thus ends up being instantiated in every translation unit.

What you want to do is *declare* it in the header file, and *define* it in the corresponding `.cpp` file:

1. Change `class Friend { ... } frnd1;` to `class Friend { ... };` in `Friend.h`.
2. Add `extern Friend frnd1;` to `Friend.h`;
3. Change `extern Friend frnd1;` to `Friend frnd1;` in `Friend.cpp`.

Friend.h:

```
class Friend
{
  ...
};

extern Friend frnd1;
```

Friend.cpp:

```
#include "Friend.h"

Friend frnd1;
```

Comment: since it violates the encapsulation concept .. Can you please tell me some cases where we need this concept .

Comment: @viku: How does it violate encapsulation? This is the way it's done in C++ (if you necessarily have to use globals, which is an encapsulation violation in itself).

Comment: @viku: Rather than start a whole separate discussion in the comments, I'd encourage you to formulate and post this as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`extern Friend frnd1;` goes in the header; `Friend frnd1;` goes in (one) .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

header:

```
class Friend
{
// ...
};

extern Friend frnd1;
```

implementation:

```
Friend frnd1;
```